# Arranging Images in a grid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of thumbnail images to be shown in a `div`. Width of the div can vary based on the screen size.The images are all of fixed size of `150px * 150px` with a padding of `5px`. I want these thumbnail images to be arranged in a grid layout and also I want these images to be center aligned with respect to the outer div. I could try `text-align: center` on the outer div.

But this way the images in the last row would appear in the center wherein I want them to be arranged from left. So i thought of calculating the free space available after placing the images and apply a `padding-left (=freespace/2)` to the outer div so that contents would appear center aligned.

This is the code I have used.

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    border: 1px solid;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 0;
}

.inner {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#position").click(function() {
        var maxCount = Math.floor($("#outer").outerWidth() / $(".inner").outerWidth());
        console.log("maxcount::" + maxCount);
        var freeSpace = $("#outer").outerWidth() - ($(".inner").outerWidth() * maxCount);
        console.log("freeSpace::" + freeSpace);
        $("#outer").css("padding-left", freeSpace / 2);
    });

    $("#text").toggle(function() {
        $("#outer").css("text-align","center");
    },function(){
        $("#outer").css("text-align","left");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="position">
    Adjust position
</button>
<button id="text">
    Toggle text align
</button>
<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fzjrm/1/

But this is not working as I expected because the contents are not perfectly center aligned. May be that logic needs some tweaking and I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Those three jsFiddle squares on the top left, top right, and bottom left are meant to get the different parts of your page; e.g., the top right is a `<body>` element wrapper, top left is for the header css, and bottom right is for header Javascript.

Comment: Yup.I know that.But i feel pasting the whole code makes it easier for people to copy the code and test it out locally :):)

Comment: Don't do that; no one does and you're more or less "breaking" how jsFiddle works (since you have a full document within a document). Not to mention you're cluttering your question with extraneous markup. To wit, you had a script include for jQuery, and jsFiddle was inserting MooTools. Use it the right way. `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I would recommend you to use `$("#outer").innerWidth()` when calculating `maxCount` as in general if you have also a padding in container, you can use only the inner part of the element.

And finally as a solution to your problem I can suggest you to add

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the `#outer` div to maintain its width. Unfortunately this doesn't work as I expect, there is a little more space from rigth side than from left. But there is another strange thing that I don't understand, those white spaces between divs (see the screenshot), I can't find CSS affecting these parts. I think that these spaces are affecting the calculation that's why I get a little more `left-padding` than we need.

Here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fzjrm/9/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. :):)..I had overlooked that margin around the inner div since i needed that margin.It was actually introduced by display inline-block style.So i tried the font-size fix specified in this url - http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ and then added my own margin. Then for the calculation I used outerWidth(true) to include margins into width calculation.The issue is now fixed.Here it the working fiddle. - http://jsfiddle.net/fzjrm/10/ ..Thanks a lot.. Without your help i would not have proceeded in this direction..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_barzilay/fy494/

What i did was instead of changing the `#outer` padding left to `freeSpace / 2` and by that increasing the size only from the left side I changed both `padding-right` and `padding-left` by `freeSpace / 4` to keep the images in the center.

```
$("#outer").css({"padding-left": freeSpace / 4, "padding-right": freeSpace / 4});
```

Comment: I don't see any differences between your result and the problem

Comment: the problam: `But this is not working as I expected because the contents are not perfectly center aligned`. and that's exactly what i fixed...

Comment: I know the problem, I mean that this doesn't fix the problem, as on my FF and Chrome the grid is still not centered